# How to search for a particular string in HTML. How to click on the link corresponding to matched string in python

Tags: html, python-2.7

below is my HTML data. I want to search for "**success**" recursively in all  **tr** blocks in my HTML data  and click on the link "**Klm_ud-gfd_hg_ghty_A_ghy**" so that it will move to next page

```
        <tr class="even">
            <td id="BuildSumBody"><a href="BuildDetails.pl?buildID=35182">Klm_ud-gfd_hg_ghty_A_ghy</a></td>
            <td id="BuildSumBody">Success</td>
            <td id="BuildSumBody"></td>
            <td id="BuildSumBody"><span class="userName">hare1 (R.)</span> <span class="userContact">user1</span></td>
            <td id="BuildSumBody"><span class="dateTime">Jan&nbsp;14,&nbsp;2016 08:39:53&nbsp;AM</span></td>
            <td id="BuildSumBody"><span class="dateTime">Jan&nbsp;14,&nbsp;2016 09:15:03&nbsp;AM</span></td>
            <td id="BuildSumBody">ghf</td>
            <td id="BuildSumBody">Dime</td>
            <td id="BuildSumBody">35182</td>
        </tr>
```

Can anyone help.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [HTMLParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html) to traverse your HTML tree and [urllib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) to get the content from the link.